# Unable to uninstall Ionic completely from Ubuntu

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have uninstalled global Ionic using the command

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
```

The Ionic package has been removed from global by

```
/usr/lib/node_modules
```

But when I run `ionic -version`, I am still getting version **4.1.1**

It's happening only on Ubuntu.
For windows, it's working fine.

The same thing is happening for typescript also.

Answer (score 1):

If you require to remove cordova and ionic from ubuntu then you uninstall using terminal command. you can uninstall cordova then you can just run bellow command. I added two command one for uninstall cordova and other uninstall ionic framework.

Example:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g cordova

sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did the same thing as you mentioned above but still I was getting ionic version **4.1.1** . I solved it by deleting the ionic file at location "**/usr/local/bin/**"

Comment: Hi, @PradeepKori ,   I think your pc included `cache file`